# Why can't I find IsAssignableFrom on VisualStudio for Mac C#? (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin

I discovered this method (Type.IsAssignableFrom) which would come in very handy, but VS (for Mac, Xamarin Forms project) labels it a missing method. (I get the red squigly) Is it deprecated or missing for the .Net version that works with Xamarin or something?

This is the code, which I got from msdn:

```
public class Example
{

public static void Main() {
  Type t = typeof(IEnumerable);
  Type c = typeof(Array);

  IEnumerable instanceOfT;
  int[] instanceOfC = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  if (t.IsAssignableFrom(c))
     instanceOfT = instanceOfC;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `using System;` included in this file?

Answer (score 2):

Since a Xamarin.Forms project is a [Portable Class Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/cross-platform/cross-platform-development-with-the-portable-class-library) with multiple target frameworks, you can only use stuff that exists in all the targets.

[MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/) that might give more information:

> With the advent of .NET Native, we have a technology that allows us to
>   statically link your application with the framework and third party
>   dependencies. For the linking to be viable, it’s important that it can
>   identify the parts of the framework that you’re not using. In other
>   technologies, such as C++, this is somewhat straightforward as these
>   systems don’t have dynamisms such as reflection. Of course, .NET
>   Native still supports reflection but we wanted to make the platform
>   more pay-for-play friendly, meaning that you don’t have to pay for
>   features that you don’t use. This is especially true for reflection,
>   as it imposes significant constraints on what the runtime and
>   compilers can do based on static information.
>
> So ideally, reflection should be an optional component in .NET Core
>   that you might decide not to use in your application at all. The
>   tricky part is that System.Object has a dependency on reflection via
>   Object.GetType(). In order to break that dependency, we decided that
>   System.Type no longer represents the full-blown reflection type
>   information but only the type name. This means that System.Type in
>   .NET Core no longer contains APIs such as GetMembers(), but continues
>   to expose APIs such as Name.
>
> In order to get access to the additional type information you have to
>   invoke an extension method called GetTypeInfo() that lives in
>   System.Reflection. It returns the new type TypeInfo which is what Type
>   used to be.

So you should be doing it like this:

```
if (t.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(c.GetTypeInfo()))
```

Removing the .NET Core target from the project should also work.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't quite explain it.  I am using System.Reflection in the Forms project and it seems to work fine for methods like object.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties, (which shows up in the code completion options), but IsAssignableFrom is nowhere to be found.